# Latex compiling out \begin{document} etc

Tags: include, preamble

I am writing a thesis with latex, each chapter is in its own TeX file and get included with a `\input{Chapters/Chapter1}` command. 
One of my Chapters is generated with Sweave (R code) and includes `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` etc at the top - this interferes with compiling the full document - so I remove them manually each time I compile.
I am looking for a way to remove these lines at compile time of the full document.
thanks.

Comment: have a look at the `docmute` package

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you cannot do this because macros like `\usepackage` can only be set in the preamble. If however, the preamble of the auto generated chapter is simple enough, and it seems to be since you said you only edit out `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`, then you can automated the processb y redefining `\documentclass` and the `document` environment in the full thesis file to do nothing but gobble their arguments. The `document` environment basically creates a group and expands `\document` at the beginning and `\enddocument` at the end.The tricky thing is that you still need to expand the final `\enddocument` that finishes the full document. You could just define `\document` to be `\def\document{\def\enddocument{}}` since `\enddocument` will be restored once the group is closed. The problem with this is the chapter will be in a different group and therefore any changes you make will not be global. So it is probably better to close the group in `\document` and let `\endocument` redefine itself. The following MWE provides one solution

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-A.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is file A
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-B.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is file B
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][]{}
\let\enddocumentOrig\enddocument
\def\document{\endgroup\def\enddocument{\def\enddocument{\enddocumentOrig}\begingroup}}

This is the main file

\input{\jobname-A}

\input{\jobname-B}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as adding the [`docmute` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute) to your preamble:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-A.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
This is file A
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-B.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
This is file B
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}

This is the main file

\input{\jobname-A}

\input{\jobname-B}

\end{document}
```

`docmute` redefines `\input` and `\include` to exclude any contents outside `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}`.

---

[`includex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/includex) (distributed with MiKTeX) provides a similar interface via `\includedoc` (there is a starred version as well).